# How to verify if a windows service is stopped or running and wait until it is in this state?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-services

How to verify if a windows service is stopped or running 
and wait until it is in this state?

```
Dim s As New ServiceController("Aservice")
    s.Refresh()
    If s.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then
        s.Stop()
    End If
    s.Refresh()
```

The problem is that I want to wait in this function until the service is in that state...
How can I do this?
tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a little While loop:

```
Dim MaxWait = 10
While Not s.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
  MaxWait = MaxWait - 1
  If MaxWait < 1 Then Break
End While
```

But you have to think about "What if it doesn't stop ?"

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim s As New ServiceController("Aservice")

While s.Status <> ServiceControllerStatus.WhatEverState
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    s.Refresh()
End While
```